# terraform fmt fails within a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I am running

```
sh "terraform fmt -list=true -write=false -diff=true -check=true"
```

within a Jenkins pipeline, and got the following weird error message:

> ERROR: Terraform Lint failed due to: hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 3
>   Finished: FAILURE

If I just run the `terraform fmt ...` without the pipeline, then it is ok. Any suggestion on how I can fix this weird error?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [Release Notes for Terraform 0.10.5](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0105-september-14-2017) (but not in the documentation), the `-check` parameter

> makes it return a non-zero exit status if any formatting changes are required

When you run it locally, it will not output any error, but if you would afterwards check the exit code `echo $?`, it would be again `3`.

In Jenkins, however, any `sh` step returning non-zero status is treated as failure. So you either remove the `-check` option, or you deal with it correctly, i.e.,

```java
def fmtStatus = sh "terraform fmt -list=true -write=false -diff=true -check=true"
if (fmtStatus == 0) {
  echo "All correct"
} else {
  echo "Changes necessary"
}
```